# I can not install any software on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation

I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 and now, whenever I install any software I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc

  dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': Is a directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: I wonder if `/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new` is a temporary location that can be deleted? I don't have this directory on my system. What is in it? Can you show the output of `ls -Al /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

This is the best solution to your problem. What happened is that the repository does not exist any more or has changed. This site has directions on how to fix the problem.
[How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)
Following these steps are necessary, you will not be able to update without following them. 
As for installing vlc, try using the software centre. I know it's a bit heavy and the terminal should work better since it's a direct link to everything, but an address or directory could have changed and it looks like you don't know it, and the list isn't updating it. I have had the same problem with plexydesk and myunity.